# DateTime.TryParse for any culture

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

There are lots of thread for this , but I am still blocked at the following:

**What I have:**

I am trying to build windows phone App which will pick Date of Birth of an individual

Code Behind:

```
string dateString = "";

  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
     if (value != null && DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(),  culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
  {
    if (dt.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
    {
      //dateString = "mm/dd/yyyy";
      return "";
    }
    else
      return dt.ToShortDateString();
  }
  else
    return dateString;
}
```

**what I need:**

I want it to parse any date format which should be culture Independent.

**What I tried:**

1.I tried using CultureInfo.InvariantCultute, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

2.Tried using ExactParser as follows:

```
string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "d/M/yyyy" , "dd/MM/yyyy" , "M/d/yyyy" ,"MM/dd/yyyy", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss",   "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss",
               "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt",  "d/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", "d/M/yyyy hh tt",
               "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "d/M/yyyy h:mm", "d/M/yyyy h:mm",
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm"};


 if (value != null && DateTime.TryParseExact(value.ToString(), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
```

but that is too hardcoded and will not cover several cases.

Is there any way to pick DOB in any format?

Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: no - since date formats can even contradict each other I don't think this is possible/viable...

Comment: Agreed with @Yahia : 10/12/2013 can be October 12th in US or December 10th in france

Comment: I agree with Yahia: You need to define what format you support. Consider the simple case of 8/9/2013. This is the 8th of September 2013 when parsed with the British format and it is the 9th of August 2013 when parsed with the American format.

Comment: Instead of taking a string use a calendar like control or ask or have separate drop downs for day, month and year. This will limit mistakes they can made, you will have less problems handling the input.

Comment: To echo the other comments - if there was a simple way to unambiguously decode any string into a `DateTime` value, do you not think that that would be a method exposed in the framework?

Comment: So the other option could be , I should ask for the culture and try to     set the CultureInfo accordingly.Am I right?

Comment: I'd have thought that, inside a windows phone app, the current thread culture should already be set appropriately - so you shouldn't be looking at methods/overloads that accept a `CultureInfo` in the first place

Answer (score 15):

Not really, because everyone has their own date formatting.

[image: Also, this!]

What you're basically trying to do is magically deduce the dates from the second half of the above XKCD [comic](http://xkcd.com/1179). ;)

That said, the only way you could TRY and do this, is to parse a string with every format you think it might be, and then make a sanity check in every case where a parse was successful. Said sanity check would be difficult however... Does 11-02 mean February 11th or November 2nd? You'd require some sort of context.

Comment: "You'd require some sort of context." - which is ... the `CultureInfo` ;-)

Comment: Assuming you HAVE the relevant `CultureInfo`. If I just tell you to parse this date `2012-01-02` would you know what I mean? At least, that's what I gathered from the question. There is of course a `CurrentCulture` setting you can gnaw at, but I've assumed this isn't enough for the OP. Otherwise... why try to parse every format in the first place?

Comment: @Shaamaan - Fortunately when a four-digit number comes first, we can infer that the format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.  There aren't *any* places AFAIK that use `YYYY-DD-MM`. ([Wikipedia concurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)).  But you are correct on all other points.  And +1 for the xkcd!

Comment: @MattJohnson I'm sure some Americans, with their annoying tendency to mix the day and month might write that way - if not officially, then unofficially. :P

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, but it seems impossible, since datetime could be *ambiguous*, and that's why *misinterpreted* e.g.

`"01/02/03"` is

```
01 Feb 2003 (Russia)

02 Jan 2003 (USA)

03 Feb 2001 (China)
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 4):

This will try all culture:

```
public static bool TryParseAnyDate(string dateValue, out DateTime result)
{
  result = DateTime.MinValue;
  foreach (CultureInfo cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
  {
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: "First one wins" is not such a great strategy for this problem.

Comment: There is no good solution to your question. If you not force the user to some format you can't tell for sure what the user "think" when enter a date. For example, based on the user's country and iq this string could be lot of thing: "05/06/07". (2007 june 5, 2007 may 6, 2005 june 7 etc.) The best solution is to use the datepicker and not let user free roam in a textbox.

Comment: +1 because in real world, you do not always control the way serialized datetime are given to you. And it is a good solution to "guess" using a well chosen format strings list (even knowing there are ambiguous cases)